# Upload Code to VSTS Team Project

Tags: azure-devops-rest-api

Is there any option of uploading code (from a zip file) to an empty VSTS team project?
I have used VSTS API([Projects](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/tfs/overview)) to create Team Project but i don't see any option there to push code to newly created VSTS project.

We can connect from Visual Studio to team project and check in code but i'm looking for some process which can add code to empty VSTS project without manual intervention.

any help/pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should uncompress zip file in an empty folder. Then commit and push the files into the new created repo.

#### Uncompress zip file:

```
string zipPath = @"C:\a\1.zip"; \\zip file you want to uncompress
string extractPath = @"C:\a\2"; \\empty path to extract files in zip
ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(zipPath, extractPath);
```

#### Add the uncompress files into git repo:

**For git repo**

You can use REST API to [add files and push to git repo](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/git/pushes#add-a-text-file).

Or you can use `System.Diagnostics.Process` to execute git commands, such as

```
ProcessStartInfo gitInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
gitInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
gitInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
gitInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
gitInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
gitInfo.FileName = @"path to git.exe"; \\such as D:\program files\Git\bin\git.exe
gitInfo.Arguments = "git remote add origin https://account.visualstudio.com/project/_git/repo";
gitInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\a\2"; \\path where extract files in

Process gitProcess = new Process();
gitProcess.StartInfo = gitInfo;
gitProcess.Start();
string stderr_str = gitProcess.StandardError.ReadToEnd();  
string stdout_str = gitProcess.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd(); 

gitProcess.WaitForExit();
gitProcess.Close();
```

**For TFVC repo**

You can use [the commands](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/use-team-foundation-version-control-commands).

Comment: Hi Marina, Git Rest API worked for me and i was able to push files to VSTS repo. I wasn't able to push(GitPush - list of changes) all the files(in a solution) in a single push due to OutOfMemory exception. and when i tried to push each folder at a time, my request is getting timed out or max size reached for the request. Could you please suggest how to overcome these?

Comment: @NareshP What's detail code? What's the total size of these files? How much free memory available?